# Shrink CSS selector for more performace

Tags: css, web, webpack, gulp, gruntjs

I started working on the last project with Grunt for compile sass, minify CSS and bundle javascript and compress images.

Is there any task runner or something else which make my css unreadable?

For Example...

From this...

```
// html
<div class="foo-bar-stylings"></div>

//css
.foo-bar-stylings {
  some: styles;
}
```

to something like this...

```
// html
<div class="wd7tg"></div>

//css
.wd7tg {
  some: styles;
}
```

Comment: may I ask why you would want to do that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067546/before-deployment-is-there-tool-to-compress-html-class-attribute-and-css-select

Comment: shrinking selectors and saving bytes I suppose @NicholasKyriakides (if server side compression is not enabled)

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides for saving bytes and speed up loading time.

//Edit: [@]fcalderan yes.

Comment: Might want to revise the question to state the actual goals and make it more clear.  Your question implies you wish to disguise the selector names, when your goal is actually just to use shorter class names and IDs for performance.

Comment: I realize you're using Grunt, but there's a Gulp package for npm that does this. Probably something similar for Grunt.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css-names

Comment: @RobertWade thanks, I am also found a grunt module for this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-rcs

Comment: @MrLister thanks, that's helpt me a lot!